# How to resolve node hanging when downloading history?

Tags: validators

I'm basically following this tutorial https://galactictalk.org/d/20-setting-up-stellar-core-on-centos-7 but on ubuntu and my node is giving the following errors:

```
Mar 26 18:14:45 stellar-node stellar-core[26007]: 2018-03-26T18:14:45.155 GAKPP [Work WARNING] Scheduling retry #7/32 in 9 sec, for get-and-unzip-remote-file bucket/b7/2b/c2/bucket-b72bc26d469a3f5079510767e2ea4773e02da574dec72e2f32f5828b79e0af40.xdr.gz
Mar 26 18:14:46 stellar-node stellar-core[26007]: 2018-03-26T18:14:46.664 GAKPP [Work WARNING] Scheduling retry #7/4294967295 in 54 sec, for ntp-work
Mar 26 18:14:54 stellar-node stellar-core[26007]: 2018-03-26T18:14:54.542 GAKPP [Process WARNING] process 26047 exited 22: curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_003/bucket/b7/2b/c2/bucket-b72bc26d469a3f5079510767e2ea4773e02da574dec72e2f32f5828b79e0af40.xdr.gz -o /var/stellar/buckets/tmp/repair-buckets-760052b9a9967061/bucket-b72bc26d469a3f5079510767e2ea4773e02da574dec72e2f32f5828b79e0af40.xdr.gz.tmp
Mar 26 18:14:54 stellar-node stellar-core[26007]: 2018-03-26T18:14:54.543 GAKPP [Work WARNING] Reached retry limit 0 for get-remote-file bucket/b7/2b/c2/bucket-b72bc26d469a3f5079510767e2ea4773e02da574dec72e2f32f5828b79e0af40.xdr.gz
Mar 26 18:14:54 stellar-node stellar-core[26007]: 2018-03-26T18:14:54.543 GAKPP [Work WARNING] Scheduling retry #8/32 in 151 sec, for get-and-unzip-remote-file bucket/b7/2b/c2/bucket-b72bc26d469a3f5079510767e2ea4773e02da574dec72e2f32f5828b79e0af40.xdr.gz
Mar 26 18:17:25 stellar-node stellar-core[26007]: 2018-03-26T18:17:25.903 GAKPP [Process WARNING] process 26066 exited 22: curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_003/bucket/b7/2b/c2/bucket-b72bc26d469a3f5079510767e2ea4773e02da574dec72e2f32f5828b79e0af40.xdr.gz -o /var/stellar/buckets/tmp/repair-buckets-760052b9a9967061/bucket-b72bc26d469a3f5079510767e2ea4773e02da574dec72e2f32f5828b79e0af40.xdr.gz.tmp
Mar 26 18:17:25 stellar-node stellar-core[26007]: 2018-03-26T18:17:25.904 GAKPP [Work WARNING] Reached retry limit 0 for get-remote-file bucket/b7/2b/c2/bucket-b72bc26d469a3f5079510767e2ea4773e02da574dec72e2f32f5828b79e0af40.xdr.gz
Mar 26 18:17:25 stellar-node stellar-core[26007]: 2018-03-26T18:17:25.905 GAKPP [Work WARNING] Scheduling retry #9/32 in 434 sec, for get-and-unzip-remote-file bucket/b7/2b/c2/bucket-b72bc26d469a3f5079510767e2ea4773e02da574dec72e2f32f5828b79e0af40.xdr.gz
```

Here's my config file:

```
# This is an example config for setting up a validator.
# see https://www.stellar.org/developers/stellar-core/learn/admin.html#validating
# it is kept up to date based on https://github.com/stellar/docs/blob/master/validators.md

# run `stellar-core --genseed` to generate a public key and secret seed.
# Let us know the public key so we can add you to the validator list.
# set NODE_SEED below to the secret seed generated above.
NODE_SEED="... tamasnagy.com"# remove this if you are non-validating
NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true

DATABASE="postgresql://dbname=core host=localhost user=stellar password=...."

#FAILURE_SAFETY is minimum number of nodes that are allowed to fail before you no longer have quorum
FAILURE_SAFETY=1

CATCHUP_RECENT=60480

NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="Public Global Stellar Network ; September 2015"

LOG_FILE_PATH="/var/log/stellar/stellar-core.log"
BUCKET_DIR_PATH="/var/stellar/buckets"


NODE_NAMES=[
"GDIQKLQVOCD5UD6MUI5D5PTPVX7WTP5TAPP5OBMOLENBBD5KG434KYQ2  stronghold1",
"GAOO3LWBC4XF6VWRP5ESJ6IBHAISVJMSBTALHOQM2EZG7Q477UWA6L7U  eno",
"GCJCSMSPIWKKPR7WEPIQG63PDF7JGGEENRC33OKVBSPUDIRL6ZZ5M7OO  tempo.eu.com",
"GC5SXLNAM3C4NMGK2PXK4R34B5GNZ47FYQ24ZIBFDFOCU6D4KBN4POAE  satoshipay",
"GCGB2S2KGYARPVIA37HYZXVRM2YZUEXA6S33ZU5BUDC6THSB62LZSTYH  sdf_watcher1",
"GCM6QMP3DLRPTAZW2UZPCPX2LF3SXWXKPMP3GKFZBDSF3QZGV2G5QSTK  sdf_watcher2",
"GABMKJM6I25XI4K7U6XWMULOUQIQ27BCTMLS6BYYSOWKTBUXVRJSXHYQ  sdf_watcher3",
"GAXEJOMEVVD5OAAGOOZ4SXTTNR46C4V23XROHWRNVEGOTGOABO3ZVH7Z  fairx",
"GAENPO2XRTTMAJXDWM3E3GAALNLG4HVMKJ4QF525TR25RI42YPEDULOW  ibm_uk"
]

KNOWN_PEERS=[
"core-live-a.stellar.org:11625",
"core-live-b.stellar.org:11625",
"core-live-c.stellar.org:11625",
"validator1.stellar.stronghold.co",
"stellar.256kw.com",
"stellar1.tempo.eu.com",
"stellar.satoshipay.io",
"uk.stellar.ibm.com",
"uswest.stellar.fairx.io"
]

[QUORUM_SET]
VALIDATORS=[
"$stronghold1", "$eno", "$tempo.eu.com", "$satoshipay", "$sdf_watcher1", "$sdf_watcher2", "$sdf_watcher3", "$fairx", "$ibm_uk"
]


# Stellar.org history store
[HISTORY.sdf1]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_001/{0} -o {1}"

[HISTORY.sdf2]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_002/{0} -o {1}"

[HISTORY.sdf3]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_003/{0} -o {1}"
```

Comment: Seeing the same errors when running `stellar-core --catchup-complete` in a `docker-stellar-core-horizon` instance on DigitalOcean with the default config

Answer (score 1):

This output basically tells you that curl could not download the file.

`[Process WARNING] process 26047 exited 22: curl -sf http://history.stellar.or...`

The process exited with a 22 code. That code is documented here alongside all other error codes: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html

```
CURLE_HTTP_RETURNED_ERROR (22) 

This is returned if CURLOPT_FAILONERROR is set TRUE and the HTTP
server returns an error code that is >= 400.
```

Your stellar-core could not download these files because the SDF history server returned an error (more specifically an HTTP status code >= 400). In most such cases the solution is to re-try later.

Answer (score 1):

I could fix this error on my end. Basically, I had to:

- Stop Core and Horizon servers
- Connect to the local postgres and delete the `stellar` and `horizon` databases
- Delete the contents of `/var/lib/stellar/buckets`
- Recreate the databases with `stellar-core --newdb` and `stellar-horizon db init`
- Start again the services

My configuration is a bit different as I used `CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true` but that's due my particular use case.

I don't understand very well the error, but I would guess that some *testnet* info in the database was mixed with public network config and when trying to download the history, that particular bucket is not found (so it's returning a permanent 404 error).